# Eclipse error 'could not determine Java version' when importing project

Tags: java, eclipse, redhat-openjdk

I'm running RHEL7 with OpenJDK 11:

```
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

with Eclipse 4.9:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
```

I've also installed the Java 11 support update referenced in this page: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49

Importing one particular project yields a dialog displaying this error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
```

The dialog appears each time I select the project in the Project Explorer view. Opening the Project Properties dialog works, but selecting Java Build Path yields another error:

```
The currently displayed page contains invalid values.
```

and I cannot view the build path settings. I have other projects working with the same configured JRE installation. What does this error mean? Is there some configuration I'm missing in this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the cause of the issue, but the solution was to regenerate the eclipse project files.

Comment: to regenerate a project do the following: 
(1) On the top menu, go to Project > Clean, and make sure Build Automatically is checked.
(2) On the Project Explorer: Right-mouse-click on the project name and go to: Maven > Update Project
(3) Run the application

Answer (score -1):

You have to add JDK-11 so, try this: project -> properties

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And select the location of your jdk-11. and then next next .....

Now check the compiler, it has to be like this:
[image]

Comment: As I said in the original post, I cannot view the Java Build Path of the project in question due to the error 'The currently displayed page contains invalid values'. After this error appears if I attempt to select other options in the Project Properties dialog I continually get the error 'The Java Build Path property change page contains unsaved modifications. Do you want to save changes so that other build path related property pages can be updated?' Then, if I click 'Apply' I get the same error as before 'Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.